# JavaScript round val to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script to calculate checkboxes as they are selected:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
  var total = 0;
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $("#total").val(total);
});
```

The `total` is showing as `46` rather than `46.00` for example. How can I ensure the number is always showing to 2 decimal places?

I added

```
console.log(format(total));
```

Which showed the correct format...

Comment: Obligatory "JavaScript is not Java" comment.

Comment: Isn't this JQuery? Assuming from the repetitive `$`'s.

Comment: @iLuvLogix - how do I amend `$("#total").val(total);` with this?

Comment: `$("#total").val(total.toFixed(2))` ...?

Comment: I suggest that you read a bit about datatypes and their methods to get more familiar with js - there's tons of material online..

Comment: `parseInt` parses values to *integers*, why would you expect decimals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
```